# how to cut the required portion of my grep output in the shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

I have a script as below

```
cdsw status|grep db-*|while read -r line ; do
    echo "Processing $line"
    # your code goes here
done
```

And the output is as below:

```
Processing |               db-86bbb69b54-p7hxm              |    1/1    |    Running    |      3       |   2020-09-11 15:36:31+00:00   |    100.66.0.7    |   10.12.33.88    |             db             |
Processing |             db-migrate-9f61bb1-dbgjm            |    0/1    |   Succeeded   |      0       |   2020-09-11 15:36:32+00:00   |    100.66.0.5    |   10.12.33.88    |         db-migrate
```

How can i implement the logic in my above shell script to get only the value `db-86bbb69b54-p7hxm` from above grep output?

Comment: Please, post some sample data (output from `cdsw status` I'd assume). Not my downvote, btw.

Answer (score 1):

Use either of these Perl one-liners:

```
# More robust, assuming the fields are separated by whitespace and pipe:
perl -F'\s*[|]\s*' -lane 'print $F[1]'

# Simpler, assuming the first two fields have no whitespace:
perl -lane 'print $F[2]'
```

For example:

```
cdsw status|grep db-*|while read -r line ; do
    echo "Processing $line"
    db=$( perl -F'\s*[|]\s*' -lane 'print $F[1]' <<< ${line} )
    echo "Processing db=${db}"
done
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)